# Get the numbers of pages selenium python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have a list of page buttons. This is HTML code.

```
<ul class="artdeco-pagination__pages artdeco-pagination__pages--number"><li class="artdeco-pagination__indicator artdeco-pagination__indicator--number ">
<button aria-label="page 1"> <span>1</span></button> </li>........</ul>
```

And so on. First thing that I am doing is to scroll the page till down, to see all the pages numbers.

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1500);")
pages= driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.artdeco-pagination__indicator')
print(len(pages))
```

The `pages` result will be 0. The `.artdeco-pagination__indicator` is not a css selector? I don't get why results is 0 and not 50...

Comment: Is there a url or more html you can share? If sharing html use snippet tool via [edit]

Comment: No. It is a code from someone. And I have to continue his work.

Comment: So you are expected to work without an url and no source html?

Comment: I updated the <ul> class. That's all I have.

Comment: the css selector is fine but with the actual page what if a wait is needed? Presumably you have verified the css selector by opening the webpage and entering it to view matches? Without a webpage or full source html I don't know how you are testing. Do you mean you are not allowed to share more than the above?

Comment: I put a time.sleep(3), and now it works:). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use Following Code :**

```
all_pageList = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[contains(@class,'artdeco-pagination__indicator')]")
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[contains(@class,'artdeco-pagination__indicator')]//button//span")[len(all_pageList)-1].text
print(len(all_pageList))
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be more robust to use an expected condition

```
pages = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.artdeco-pagination__indicator')))
```

Additional imports

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```